# Uncaught Type Error: Object `function()` has no method 'call'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, web

I have an AJAX request that utilizes `beforeSend`, `success`, and `failure`, yet when the `beforeSend` gets hit it treats it as an object instead of a method call.

Here's the AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("DeleteUser", "DataFeeds")/" + id,
    method: 'post',
    beforeSend: "deleting('" + id + "')",
    success: "deleted('" + full + "','" + id + "')",
    failure: "failed('" + id + "')"
});
```

Just for kicks, here's the `deleting()` method:

```
function deleting(id) {
    $('#btnDelete-' + id + ' span').html('Deleting...');
    $('#btnDelete-' + id + ' span').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

It's pretty simple stuff, but I can't figure out why it's treating my function as an object.

Halp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an extra anonymous function there, otherwise you're just assigning a string:

```
beforeSend: function(){ deleting(id) },
// same with the other methods...
```

Comment: Great. Remember functions are objects and should be always passed as objects, _not_ strings. In places that functions can be used as strings you're actually triggering `eval`, no good...

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken, but I don't think you're allowed to give JQuery a string there.  You can give it a function instead by currying `deleting`:

```
function deleting(id) {
    return function() {
        $('#btnDelete-' + id + ' span').html('Deleting...');
        $('#btnDelete-' + id + ' span').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
}
```

And:

```
beforeSend: deleting(id),
```